# udevadm slow boot

Tags: boot, performance, slackware

After I upgraded from Slackware 13.70 to 14.0, when the machine is booting, it takes it 15 seconds to execute this line:

> /sbin/udevadm trigger --action=add

I understand, that it tries to detect the new hardware. But it's really long.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to modify the line that's calling udevadm like so to gain more insight into what's going on:

```
/sbin/udevadm trigger --action=add --verbose
```

Comment: /sys/devices/virtual/block/md0 is causing the delay

Comment: You have a RAID device on this box?

Comment: Take a look at this forum, they are having similar issues, looks like a possible issue with motherboards, some fixes are to disable/enable various features of the kernel at boot through: http://forum.porteus.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=915

Comment: "You have a RAID device on this box?" no